# The value of an input that is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn jQuery and Ajax. If I understand well, it is not possible to store the value of an input if that input is loaded. Is that correct?

index.php:

```
$("#content").load("proces.php");
    $(':button').click(function() {
        var dynamicValue = $('#inputfield').val();
        alert (dynamicValue);
});
```

process.php:

```
<input type="text" id="inputfield" />
```

Comment: it's entirely possible, but `.load()` is an asynchronous call. It'll return IMMEDIATELY, and then your button code will run, BEFORE the .load() has had a chance to actually do its thing, so you're trying to attach to a button which doesn't exist (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but you should wait for content to be loaded before reading Binding the event :

```
$("#content").load("proces.php", function(){
    $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        var value = $('#inputField').val();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

This suppose that your `process.php` contains something like

```
<input type="text" id="inputfield" />
```

And there is button with id `myBtn` in your HTML

Comment: The second parameter of the `load()` method in this example is a callback; it executes once the load has completed. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more detail.

Comment: I undertstand. Perfect answer. Thank you.

Comment: But how would be with the code I provide?. I mean if the value of the input is provided by the user, when the user enters to index.php

Comment: I edited my answer, hope this fits your needs. If any other question just ask